# Embed image in CakePHP3 Email

Tags: php, email, cakephp-3.x

#### Original Question

I am sending an email using CakePHP 3's Mailer Aware trait.

My mail is being sent with this function:

```
public function forgotPassword($user,$password)
{
    $this
        ->from(['no-reply@deltabec.com' => 'DeltaBEC Intraweb'])
        ->emailFormat('html')
        ->to([$user->email => $user->name . ' ' . $user->surname])
        ->subject('New Intraweb Password')
        ->template('Users' . DS . 'forgot_password', 'default')
        ->attachments([[
            'file' => WWW_ROOT . 'img' . DS . 'logo-dark.png',
            'mimetype' => 'image/png',
            'contentId' => 'company_logo'
        ]])
        ->viewVars(compact('user','password'));
}
```

In my email I have this:

```
<?= $this->Html->image('cid:company_logo'); ?>
```

But my mail comes through like this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Is there a reason it's not embedding the image in the email?

#### EDIT 1 - Discovery

So I took the email and saved it as html. This is what it shows me:

```
<img id="_x0000_i1025" src="/cakesite/img/cid%3Acompany_logo">
```

Seems it's encoding the link and placing a whole URL instead of just the `cid`

#### EDIT 2 - Feature request

I'd expect it to work the way I used it. There's nothing fundamentally wrong with the way I did it, so I added a ticket on [Github](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/8877) so it can be discussed, and hopefully it get's added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The HTML helpers `image()` method, respectively the URL helper, doesn't recognize the special `cid` scheme, or any other scheme that doesn't use `//` after the `:`, and therefore will try to create an image asset URL.

This may be something for an enhancement request, or maybe even considered as a bug, so you may want to open a ticket [**over at GitHub**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues).

For now, just ditch using the helper and create the `<img>` tags manually.

Comment: This is what I did just before your answer. However, it is correct. Using `<img src="cid:company_logo">` fixed the issue and the image is now embedded. I will upvote and mark as accepted.